# Flask can't direct to HTML Files

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

So I have a flask code that works for the index.html page. However, When I click on other links such as permission.html it doesn't show any content of permission.html and I get `127.0.0.1 - - [10/May/2020 08:21:46] "GET /permission.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -`. How do I redirect to permission.html and it shows it's contents?

My file structure

```
.
├── code.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── style.css
│   └── pictures
│       └── some_picture.png
└── templates
    ├── index.html
    ├── permission.html
    ├── shell.sh
```

Code.py

```
from flask import Flask, url_for
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/permission.html')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img class="resize" src="/static/pictures/logo.png" alt="logo">
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li class="active"><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="./permission.html">Permission</a></li>
            </ul>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).on('click', 'ul li', function(){
                    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
                })
            </script>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

permission.html

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body, html
        {
            margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img class="resize" src="../static/pictures/logo.png" alt="logo">
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="./permission.html">Permission</a></li>
            </ul>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).on('click', 'ul li', function(){
                    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
                })
            </script>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="some_url"></iframe>
    <p>HII</p>
</body>
</html>
```

What needs to be changed in terms of directing to other links? And properly displaying its contents along with its CSS?

Comment: You need to create another view that renders `permission.html` template and bind it for example to the URL `/permission.html`. Also, you need to remove the binding URL of permission in your index view function.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off using separate routes for these separate pages, like so:

```py
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/permission')
def permission():
    return render_template('permission.html')
```

See excellent comment below for linking.

Comment: It would be better if you use Jinja tags `{{ url_for('permission') }}` to render the URL in the template. See the the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/0.12.x/tutorial/templates/)

Comment: somehow i still have the issue

Comment: Please edit question with updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Following piece of code is telling flask to render `index.html` when a request for `/` or `/permission.html` is made.

```py
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/permission.html')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

`@app.route(/endpoint)` decorator tells flask to run method decorated with it when a request to `/endpoint` is made. flask then uses return code of that method to make a response. So you need to create one for `/permission.html` endpoint:

```py
from flask import Flask, url_for
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/permission.html')
def permission():
    return render_template('permission.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

See more about routing rules and `app.route()` [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.route).

Also you probably don't want `{% extends 'index.html' %}` in your permission.html as that tells Jinja (flask template rendered) to take index.html and only replace certain blocks in it by contents of permission.html. You provide complete HTML file so there's no need to have `extends` directive. See more about how to use extends [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#template-inheritance).

Comment: somehow it still doesn't show the contents

Comment: When you click the link what do you see in terminal where your flask is running? Is there any error?

Comment: i got ```127.0.0.1 - - [10/May/2020 08:44:20] "GET /permission.html HTTP/1.1" 404 -```

Comment: I edited my linking to ```{{ url_for('permission') }} ``` and got ```127.0.0.1 - - [10/May/2020 08:45:06] "GET /permission HTTP/1.1" 200 -```

Comment: Flask doesn't see the new route. Do you run development server on Windows by chance? Sometimes autoreload on Windows is a bit flaky. Does it work if you quit (CTRL+C) and re-run flask again?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here you have linked both the paths to the same file i.e. index .html. You can try

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/permission')
def permission():
    return render_template('permission.html')
```

Comment: It still doesn't render

Comment: oops the code is not proper , i have updated it now. and also you might want to get rid of `{% extends 'index.html' %}`